# Xephyr - Two Displays as extended view

Tags: xephyr

I have a wide monitor and I would like to use Xephyr or any other option to create two displays as extended view. Why?
I use to connect to a remote server (RDP) that has two monitors and I am able to see only one remote screen, but if I use two monitors, I can get the two remote views.
I am using Linux Mint (but I can move to any other distro if required).
I have installed Xephyr and it is useful as independent view.

Thanks